# Want to increase dynamic array by use realloc and not successful

Tags: c, linker-errors

```
void main()
{
    int *ptr, size, i;
    printf("size is:\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    ptr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return;
    }
    ptr = (int*)realloc(ptr, (size + 10) * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i <size+10; i++)
    {
        printf("number %d...\n", i);
        scnaf("%d", &ptr[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size + 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", ptr[i]);
    }
    free(ptr);
}
```

Want to create a dynamic array, add 10 more places in memory, and absorb the values from the user.
for example, if the user enters 5 for the size, the total size will be size=5+10=15, and if the user then enters:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

the output will be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

The errors I get are :

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _scnaf referenced in function _main  realloc 
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  realloc
```

Can you try and help me understand why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Note that you should not use `ptr = realloc(ptr, new_size);` if `ptr` is the only variable containing current block address because the failure of allocation the return value of `realloc` is `NULL` and then you have neither the new block address nor the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Secondly there is a typo. You wrote `scnaf` instead of `scanf`.

And you have to include headers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t size;

    printf( "size is: " );
    scanf( "%zu", &size );

    int *ptr = malloc( size * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( ptr == NULL )
    {
        puts( "Error" );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int *tmp = realloc( ptr, ( size + 10 ) * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        size += 10;
        ptr = tmp;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        printf("number %zu => ", i );
        scanf( "%d", ptr + i );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", ptr[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    free( ptr );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
size is: 5
number 0 => 1
number 1 => 2
number 2 => 3
number 3 => 4
number 4 => 5
number 5 => 6
number 6 => 7
number 7 => 8
number 8 => 9
number 9 => 10
number 10 => 11
number 11 => 12
number 12 => 13
number 13 => 14
number 14 => 15
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: You've duped my answer :-)

Comment: And mine ;) ;) ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code resulting in errors.

1. You mistyped scnaf instead of scanf, like @VillageTech noted.
2. You need to include the appropriate standard library headers: `scanf()` comes from [`<stdio.h>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/) and `realloc()` from [`<stdlib.h>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/).

If you fix that, your code [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/gJUcAi) (GodBolt.org). It also runs mostly as you would expect.

Note also that "size is:"  is a very ambiguous message, and the user will be confused regarding what to do and what to expect later.

There are also other issues with your code, such as failing to check for errors returned from `scanf()`, or the assumption that `realloc()` was successful - see @6502's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I agree, will not smile ;)
This is `scanf()`, not `scnaf()` :) :) :)

So:

```
scanf("%d", &ptr[i]);
```